# Python websocket: Import error, cannot import 'create_connection' in docker

Tags: python, docker, websocket

So I am using websocket in my program. In the file I am importing create_connection from websocket.

```py
from websocket import create_connection
```

Problem is, when I run this off my venv with a requirements.txt, pip installs from, where both websocket and websocket-client is, my program runs fine.

But when I do a docker container, that pip installs from the exact same requirements.txt file and runs the exact same script with the import, I get ImportError: cannot import name 'create_connection' from 'websocket'.

What am I doing wrong? Everything else in my docker container works fine (I am doing other installs in the requirements.txt, like pandas and numpy) and the program runs fine when I just run it in the console, instead of a docker.

Comment: Can you post your `Dockerfile`?

Comment: I managed to fix it by adding seperate RUN pip install websocket and RUN pip install websocket-client
 which is wierd as I am still doing RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
for all the other dependencies which work fine, but for websocket, it doesn't work for some reason.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to fix the issue by adding seperate RUN pip install for both websocket, and websocket-client in the dockerfile. It's weird that I need to, as both are in the requirements.txt but idk. It works

```
FROM python:3.8

COPY requirements.txt .

RUN pip install numpy 

RUN wget http://prdownloads.sourceforge.net/ta-lib/ta-lib-0.4.0-src.tar.gz && \
  tar -xvzf ta-lib-0.4.0-src.tar.gz && \
  cd ta-lib/ && \
  ./configure --prefix=/usr && \
  make && \
  make install

RUN rm -R ta-lib ta-lib-0.4.0-src.tar.gz

RUN pip install TA-Lib

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

RUN pip install websocket

RUN pip install websocket-client

COPY ./app ./app

CMD python app/startup.py
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error message on the system-wide installation of Python on my PC (no docker).

The problem remedied itself by installing `websockets` and `websocket-client`
with the root user, i.e.

`sudo pip3 install websockets`

so the packages were installed to `/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages` instead of `/home/$USER/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages`.

Since docker uses the root user for everything, I am not sure whether this explains your problem.

Also note that the websocket packet is called `websockets`. The singular name [websocket](https://pypi.org/project/websocket/) will install some gevent library.